# Unpermitted params when creating a devise user with nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, nested-forms, strong-parameters

I'm currently trying to create a devise user with some nested attributes.  Each `User` `has_many :companies` and also `accepts_nested_attributes_for :companies`.  When a user is added to the system by an admin, I want to automatically create a corresponding `Company` and get some of its basic information right in the user registration form.  This means that I'm nesting some `Company` fields in form.

**The problem** is that, while I'm able to create a user just fine, the nested company is rejected with the error.

> Unpermitted parameter: company

### Below is my code

**application_controller.rb** note: `companies_params` are just in there to see if that was needed (I don't actually know if they're necessary)

```
before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

protected

    def configure_permitted_parameters
            devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) {|u|
                    u.permit(:password, :password_confirmation, :current_password, companies_attributes: [:id, :name, :street, :city, :state, :zip, :_destroy])}
            devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) {|u|
                    u.permit(:password, :password_confirmation, :current_password, companies_attributes: [:id, :name, :street, :city, :state, :zip, :_destroy])}
    end
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
def new
    @user=User.new
    @company=@user.companies.build
end

def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
        redirect_to users_admin_path(@user), notice: "User successfuly created!"
    else
        redirect_to welcome_index_path
    end
end

private

def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:id, :email, :role, :password, :password_confirmation, companies_attributes: [:id, :name, :street, :city, :state, :zip, :_destroy])
end
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_form_for @user, url: url_for(action: 'create', controller: 'users') do |f| %>
    <fieldset>
        <ol>

            <li class="required">
                <%= f.label :email %>
                <%= f.email_field :email, size: 40 %>
            </li>
            <li class="required">
                <%= f.label :password %>
                <%= f.password_field :password, size: 40 %>
            </li>
            <li class="required">
                <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirm Password" %>
                <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, size: 40 %>
            </li>

        </ol>
        <%= f.simple_fields_for @company do |company| %>
            <div class="field">
                <%= company.input :name, label: "Name" %>
            </div>
        <% end %>
        <%= f.submit "Create Account" %>
    </fieldset>
<% end %>
```

Any ideas would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Objects**

To give you some context, you have to remember that when you use [`form_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html), it's aim is to build a single object (in this case, `@user`).

When you use [`f.fields_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for), you're invoking *nested* attributes of this object.

Thus, you have to invoke `fields_for` as a part of the parent object. Your passing `@company` will not work as you need; you need to invoke a nested element of the *parent* object, which is why only the following work:

```
<%= f.fields_for :companies ... %>
<%= f.fields_for @user.companies .... %>
```

This, of course, has to accompany the `build` command - to construct the nested object in the controller, which you've done already...

```
def new
    @user = User.new
    @user.companies.build
end
```

--

I'll delete this answer if it's too broad - I felt it proper to clarify the situation for anyone who might find this question.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there was a problem with how I was nesting `:companies` in `simple_fields_for`.

Turns out that one can only use

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :companies do |company| %>
```

**OR**

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for @user.companies do |company| %>
```

But **never**

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for @company do |company| %>
```